# Convert YYYY-mm-dd to a specific locale name in php

Tags: php

How can i convert a date in format `yyyy-mm-dd` to `month-dd-yyyy` in ro_RO locale ?

The date is outputed by `<?php echo ($_GET["date"]);?>`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks. I have edit the title. Anyway i have checked that question beforem but i need to convert my date in the Romanian locale .is there a code to force the php to use the ro_RO locale ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From PHP > 5.3 you can use [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php)

```
$dt = new DateTime('2015-02-01'); // Date in yyyy-mm-dd format

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('ro_RO', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT); // Set locale name
$formatter->setPattern('MMMM dd yyyy'); // Return date in month-dd-yyyy format

echo $formatter->format($dt); // Format date
```

See it in action : http://3v4l.org/bQNah